# Placing playbutton inside an image

Tags: html, css, image, audio

What I'm trying to do is place the audio button, inside the image code. Can someone help me do this? The entire code is in the jsfiddle. It keeps saying to add more info but that's all I'm asking for help with. Can someone help me do this please. It keeps saying to add more info but that's all I'm asking for help with.

Working Code

https://jsfiddle.net/7h8jsvch/1/

**Image / Audio Button**

[image]

```html
<style>
#container {
    background-color: black;
    position:relative; 
    width:260px;
    height:194px;
    padding:0;
    border: 3px solid #0059dd;
}

#img1,#img2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

#img1 {
    clip-path: circle(85px at center);
}
  
#grad {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 260px; 
    height: 194px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent; ; 
    background-image: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 0, transparent  83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, transparent 177px,transparent 260px ); 
   
  }

  .button div {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    top: 76px;
    left: 111px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: 14px 18px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
  }

</style>

<div id="container">
    <img id="img1" width="170" height="113" src="https://i.imgur.com/BO6KOvw.jpg">
    <img id="img2" width="180" height="180" src="https://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png">
    <div id="grad">



</div>
</div>


<div id="playButton4" style="position:relative;border: 3px solid #0059dd;background-color:black;width: 260px; height: 194px;cursor: pointer;" onclick=" 
var button = document.getElementById('playButton4');
var player = document.getElementById('player4');
button.querySelector('.play').style.display='none';
button.querySelector('.pause').style.display='none';
player.volume=1.0; if (player.paused) {
button.querySelector('.pause').style.display='inline-block';
player.play();
} else {
button.querySelector('.play').style.display='inline-block';
player.pause();
}">

 

  <div class="button">
    <div class="play" style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMjI2IDE0ODEiPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wIDEzOTRWODdDMCA0Ni4zIDEzLjMgMTkuOCA0MCA3LjUgNjYuNy00LjggOTguNy4zIDEzNiAyM2wxMDM0IDYzNGMzNy4zIDIyLjcgNTYgNTAuMyA1NiA4M3MtMTguNyA2MC4zLTU2IDgzTDEzNiAxNDU4Yy0zNy4zIDIyLjctNjkuMyAyNy44LTk2IDE1LjUtMjYuNy0xMi4zLTQwLTM4LjgtNDAtNzkuNXoiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDU5ZGQiLz4KIDwvc3ZnPg=='); background-position: 58% 50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="pause" style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');background-position: 50%;display: none;">
    </div>

  </div>


</div>

<audio id="player4" style="display:none;">
  <source src='http://hi5.1980s.fm/;' type='audio/mpeg'>
  </source>
</audio>
```

Comment: please use stack overflows code snippet feature instead of jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your `playButton4` div and `button` div inside the container. Also remove background color and border of `playButton4` div.

```css
#container {
    background-color: black;
    position:relative; 
    width:260px;
    height:194px;
    padding:0;
    border: 3px solid #0059dd;
}

#img1,#img2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

#img1 {
    clip-path: circle(85px at center);
}
  
#grad {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 260px; 
    height: 194px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent; ; 
    background-image: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 0, transparent  83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, transparent 177px,transparent 260px ); 
   
  }

  .button div {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    top: 76px;
    left: 111px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: 14px 18px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img id="img1" width="170" height="113" src="https://i.imgur.com/BO6KOvw.jpg">
    <img id="img2" width="180" height="180" src="https://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png">
    <div id="grad">


<div id="playButton4" style="position:relative;width: 260px; height: 194px;cursor: pointer;" onclick=" 
var button = document.getElementById('playButton4');
var player = document.getElementById('player4');
button.querySelector('.play').style.display='none';
button.querySelector('.pause').style.display='none';
player.volume=1.0; if (player.paused) {
button.querySelector('.pause').style.display='inline-block';
player.play();
} else {
button.querySelector('.play').style.display='inline-block';
player.pause();
}">

 

  <div class="button">
    <div class="play" style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMjI2IDE0ODEiPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wIDEzOTRWODdDMCA0Ni4zIDEzLjMgMTkuOCA0MCA3LjUgNjYuNy00LjggOTguNy4zIDEzNiAyM2wxMDM0IDYzNGMzNy4zIDIyLjcgNTYgNTAuMyA1NiA4M3MtMTguNyA2MC4zLTU2IDgzTDEzNiAxNDU4Yy0zNy4zIDIyLjctNjkuMyAyNy44LTk2IDE1LjUtMjYuNy0xMi4zLTQwLTM4LjgtNDAtNzkuNXoiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDU5ZGQiLz4KIDwvc3ZnPg=='); background-position: 58% 50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="pause" style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');background-position: 50%;display: none;">
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
</div>



</div>

<audio id="player4" style="display:none;">
  <source src='http://hi5.1980s.fm/;' type='audio/mpeg'>
  </source>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

place the play button inside of the container div and I would suggest removing the black background from the play button as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/7h8jsvch/7/

```
    <div id="container">
    <img id="img1" width="170" height="113" 
src="https://i.imgur.com/BO6KOvw.jpg">
    <img id="img2" width="180" height="180" 
src="https://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png">
    <div id="grad">
    <div id="playButton4" style="position:relative;border: 3px solid 
#0059dd;width: 260px; height: 194px;cursor: pointer;" onclick=" 
var button = document.getElementById('playButton4');
var player = document.getElementById('player4');
button.querySelector('.play').style.display='none';
button.querySelector('.pause').style.display='none';
player.volume=1.0; if (player.paused) {
button.querySelector('.pause').style.display='inline-block';
player.play();
} else {
button.querySelector('.play').style.display='inline-block';
player.pause();
}">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no need for jsfiddle, you should use stack overflows `code snippet`